# Example of fibre bundle is locally product but not globally

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

When I read the below picture ,I can't make a example for claim of  red box.

> [image]

Comment: See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration.

Comment: Simpler one: $E = S^1 \to S^1$, $z\mapsto z^2$ is fiber bundle over $S^1$ with fiber $F = \{ \pm 1\}$.

Comment: @JohnMa Why  $F = \{ \pm 1\}$ ?

Comment: It just mean that the fiber is formed by two elements. @lanse7pty

Comment: @JohnMa So, the $S^1$ is not $S^1\times \{\pm 1\}$ .clever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you heard of non-trivial covering spaces?  --- fiber bundles with discrete fiber!

Have you heard of the Möbius Band? --- fiber bundle over the circle with an interval as fiber!

Both examples are non trivial (i.e. not product bundles).

Comment: I know Mobius band, and seemly, I understand the example .Whether it is that :$S^1\times [0,1]$ is cylinder  not Mobius band .